# Passing values from router to view in node js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to pass a message from router to my ejs view index. but when i load the view on browser it says the object key is undefined

```
    if(data != null){
        if(data.name == req.body.name){
            res.render('index', {err: 'The name already exist'});
        }
    }
```

this is the statement and i'm trying to display this error when user clicks submit button

this is the EJS template codes i'v used to display the error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add names</h1>
<p>Enter your name to add it into a database</p>
<form method="POST" action="/names">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name here" required/>
    </br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<%for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){%>
    <p>This is your name: <%=data[i].name%></p>
<%}%>

<p><%=err%></p>

</body>
</html>
```

the error shows me as (err is not defined)

thank you

Comment: Sounds like an error in the template. What does your template look like?

Comment: it's a ejs template so it has a form and one input field. so and the last thing i'm displaying some data retrieving from the db collection thats all in the template view

Comment: Posting the code may help. It's really hard to guess what's going on only with your description. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok i'll edit the question again within including the ejs template code

Comment: If you use variables in a template, make sure they actually exist (they may be empty, or `null`, but they have to be defined). In the code you're showing, you're not defining `data` so when that code runs EJS will throw an error because it's trying resolve `data.length`. EJS are simple templates, any code you're using in it should be valid JS.

Comment: there were no issues with data.name i mean the below EJS cod err as i mentioned with the if statement and the actual issue within res.render('index' {err: 'This is the message i wanna display on EJS file'}); check it carefully #robertklep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the existence of the variables or values you parse to ejs template. On your EJS template, try the following changes

```
    <%if(typeof(data) != 'undefined'){for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){%>
        <p>This is your name: <%=data[i].name%></p>
    <%}}%>

    <%if(typeof(err) != 'undefined'){%>
<p><%=err%></p>
<%}%>
```

Cheers!